# Create second, fully customisable loop page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to do something with a website I'm working on. This is my first time using Wordpress, and I've got most of the things I need to work running fine.

However, I'd like to create another page on my website that can display loop posts that is formatted completely different from the normal index.php file.

For example, index.php has it's own loop, and acts as the website homepage. The second page would be called roster.php, and has a loop that displays and formats posts from a specific category of posts. If this is possible, where would I create the roster.php file, and would it still work properly with my Wordpress installation?

I've dug around the Wordpress Codex, and done several Google searches on this subject, but I can't seem to find anything similar to this scenario. Or maybe I've just misunderstood them all.

I really appreciate your time reading this post, anything you can contribute would be extremely useful to me.

Thanks again, Callum Kerr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a page `roster` in wordpress and a page-roster.php in your template directory. Wordpress will automatically route the page to the php file.

You can then do a custom search & loop in page-roster.php

Comment: Ohhh, the template directory! I was creating the file in the same place as the index.php, header.php and so on. That works exactly as I need it to, thank you so much!

Comment: Just so it's easier to link to, do you know how I would change the page name to roster.php from "domain.com?page_id=91" without upsetting the other pages?

Comment: @CallumKerr If you don't use wordpress pretty urls, you'd have to write a rewrite rule in your .htaccess (assuming you're using apache, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

Comment: Neat, I'll look into that. Thank's again :)

Answer (score 1):

page-roster.php should do the trick!

Check this for more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#What_Template_is_Used_to_Display_a_Particular_Page.3F

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom Templates for your pages, posts and even categories, [this Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) may help you with examples on how to do it.